# React pass using useNavigate cannot read properties of null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using useNavigate to pass data between components.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Categories() {
const navigate = useNavigate();
.
.
onClick={() => navigate("/books", {state:{ name: categorie.name }})}
```

Then I resive the data from second component

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
function Books() {
const location = useLocation();
let currentcategory = location.state.name;
```

Its works fine but If I try to access directly using URL https://localhost/books

I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that the route/link/navigate state ***only exists*** if you transition from the component providing the state. If you manually enter the receiving route's URL path in the address bar, this state is missing, or undefined/null.

In other words, `location.state` is undefined/null, and the error is thrown when accessing further into it to get `location.state.name`.

## Solution

Use a null-check/guard-clause or the Optional Chaining operator to defend against the potentially null access, or provide a fallback value to destructure from.

- Null-check/guard-clause

  ```
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const currentCategory = state && state.name;
  ```
- Optional Chaining operator

  ```
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const currentCategory = state?.name;
  ```
- Fallback object to destructure from

  ```
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { name: currentCategory } = state || {};
  ```

Answer (score 1):

you need to destructure it

```
const {state} = useLocation();
console.log(state)
```

Comment: I got undefined ( on console.log )

Comment: not sure what's going wrong it works fine for me check [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leftpad-70d1z9?file=/src/Login.js)

Comment: check if you directly use this URL https://70d1z9.csb.app/signup 
in your project you well got same error
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Comment: I used useEffect to check if I received data or I received null.

Comment: how can you expect this to work ? you are passing data from one component to another if you hit that `URL` directly how will router get to know what data to load ?

Comment: I tried like this 

 if (state === null){
      ....
    }
    else {
      ...
}

I'm not sure if there is better way or not